# Is the ApplicationRegistry available on linux

Tags: install4j

I want install4j to detect if the application is installed on the customer's Linux box, but it might be installed in a non-standard location.  Is this possible?  I found some code in the code gallery that seems to work on Windows, but I don't see how this can be done on Linux:

installationApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo applicationInfo =
    ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoByDir(context.getInstallationDirectory());

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work on Linux, but it uses the Java preference store. If you do not install as root, this information will be in the user-specific preference store, so the installer will only see the previous installations if you use the same user to run the installer.

Comment: Aha!  I see the path to the installation in /root/.java/.userPrefs/com/install4j/installations/prefs.xml -- Thanks!

Comment: The trick was to use ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoById().  For an add-on installer, Install4j did not initially set sys.installationDir to the previous installation.